# What does 'good' mean in Curious badge definition?

Tags: discussion, badges

Example:

> You've earned the "Curious" badge (Asked a good question on 5 seperate days, and maintains a positive question record.)

Is there some kind of metric? (votes, answers, ???)

## update:

Meta-Stack-Exchange discussion:

- [Misleading description of new Curious badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234956/misleading-description-of-new-curious-badge)

Comment: was this badge just added recently? I got mine just an hour ago and was about to ask the same question...

Comment: @marczking correct.  There're also silver and gold versions at 30 and 100 questions.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Please see the MSE question about it: [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234259/229438)

> A well-received question is one that's open, not deleted, and has a score > 0.

Comment: How long should a question remain "well-received" before getting the Curious Badge?