# Reword "a good question" in curious, inquisitive, and socratic badges

Tags: discussion, badges

The definition of "a good question" is unclear, especially since the "good question" badge is defined exactly 5 lines below

```
Curious:  Asked a good question on 5 separate days, and maintains a positive question record.  
Inquisitive:  Asked a good question on 30 separate days, and maintains a positive question record.  
Socratic:  Asked a good question on 100 separate days, and maintains a positive question record.
```

5 lines below that:

```
Good Question:  Question score of 25 or more
```

The badge actually means: [not deleted, and score >0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262328/2502012)

How can this be reworded to be more clear?

Comment: This issue has already been handled on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234956/misleading-description-of-new-curious-badge

Comment: @murgatroid99 didnt know about MSE, is that a new meta site?

Comment: Yes, that is the meta site that covers the whole network.